# excel vba need control that will check is theere empty cell

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

```
    Private Function test()
    Dim S1 As String, S2 As String

    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("pppdp")
    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 19 To lRow
    End Function
```

Hi, I have excel worksheet for exporting table to *xml*, so I need control that will check is there empty cell in range A to R, I started with this but I stopped there and don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there empty cell in range A to R?

The logic is to check if the total cell count is equal to the total cells filled.

Like this?

```
Sub Sample()
    If test = False Then
        MsgBox "Range A to R has empty cells"
    Else
        MsgBox "No Empty Cells"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function test() As Boolean
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("pppdp")

    With ws
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Range("A:R").Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            lRow = 1
        End If

        test = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A1:R" & lRow)) _
             = .Range("A1:R" & lRow).Cells.Count
    End With
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: works great, thank. it would be nice if it could mark empty cells with red color, that would help a lot

Comment: I can give you the answer but would you like to try it first? ;) Read the inbuilt Excel help on `Range.SpecialCells Method`

Comment: to be honest i don't have a clue what i should do :) , so i would be grateful if u help me

Comment: `i don't have a clue what i should do :)` I just told you what to do. Open Excel help and see the example for `Range.SpecialCells Method` The reason why I answered your question because I saw efforts from your side. :) Now show me the same efforts for `Range.SpecialCells Method` and if you are stuck I will help you... It's a promise... Now the ball is in your court :)

Comment: ok i work out something but i'm stuck again... this is what i got      `Sub testiranje()
With Sheets("pppdp")
  If Not test Then
    .Range("A19:R" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
  End If
End With
End Sub` problem is that when i fill empty cells they stay red